# If I run a node.js app in Docker Compose with "restart: always", do I still need a process manager like PM2?

Tags: docker-compose, next.js, pm2, production-environment

After reading the node.js, PM2 and Docker documentation, it's still difficult to make a conclusion whether I need a process manager to run a node.js application if I use docker-compose in production?

My goals are:

- if my Next.js application dies, I need the error logged for further investigation AND the app restarted
- if it makes sense, I'd like to run two instances and proxy to them through Nginx or Caddy; so that if one of the instances dies, the other can still server the requests while the first one gets restarted

So, the question is, does using Docker Compose with "restart always" fully replace a process manager like PM2 as far as I'm concerned re uninterrupted access to the node.js application?